# Android Studio - disable gradle sync

Tags: android-studio

Every time I load Android Studio (1.5), it runs gradle sync, even though nothing has changed since the last run. The funny thing is that a project that sync-ed properly yesterday will fail for random reasons today. Such as "Error:Cause: peer not authenticated" or "Could not reserve enough space for object heap".

Could I disable automatic gradle sync at startup?

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT: It looks like this feature has been removed in the latest versions.**

This is a little late, but for anyone else looking:

In "Settings" -> "Appearance & Behavior" -> "System Settings"

Uncheck "Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation"

You'll have to remember to hit the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button whenever you make changes to Gradle. (To the left of AVD Manager)

Comment: Confirmed that this works (Android Studio 2.2.3).  Next up is how to disable gradle BUILD on startup...

Comment: I can't find this option on Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2

Comment: @TamimAttafi, I'm running Flamingo and it looks like they removed this option. I can't find any alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable autoimport in `Settings (Preferences) > Build... > Build Tools > Gradle`

See [How to disable automatic gradle builds?](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205990224-How-to-disable-automatic-gradle-builds-)

Comment: I think this setting in the place you are referring to doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable auto sync using below steps

Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings 
Uncheck Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

My gradle kept syncing files automatically whenever I changed something to my `build.gradle`, this became so annoying since it doesn't give you the chance to finish writing something before switching you to another tab.

None of the answers above helped me, so I updated my version from `Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2` to `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1` and still had the issue.

The option `Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation` under `Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings` is mussing in these new versions.

## The Solution

It seems like the new Android Studio versions have a bug that was causing this issue. So in order to fix it, follow these steps:

1. Open your `gradle` side panel (Right side)
2. Click on the three dots to show more options
3. Click on `Auto-Reload Settings`
   [image]
4. Check the option `Reload project after changes in the build scripts`
5. Check the option `External changes`
   [image]
6. Uncheck the option `Reload project after changes in the build scripts`
   [image]

You can find this option under `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools`

Or if you are using MacOS `Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools`

Restart Android Studio

## Happy Coding!