# Android Studio - automatic gradle sync at startup

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

Yesterday I updated the Android Studio to 2.2 (from 2.1.3). Since that the Android Studio always start gradle sync at startup on every opened projects. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402973/android-studio-disable-gradle-sync) question and I tried [Mick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3830712/mick)'s suggestion, but unfortunately that did'nt worked for me.
If I open Android Studio, and I wait until load my projects, sync gradle and then I close Android Studio (without any change on my projects), and after that, I open it again, AS also do the same as before (run a gradle sync again senselessly).
I think, this is not a serious problem, but it's pretty weird, because it sync senselessly (otherwise I start gradle sync manually if I need to, but AS start it on every startup senselessly), and I need to wait little more to start coding (a little waste of time and energy).

Comment: If your project used gradle then you should not disable automatic sync gradle project. And anyway you have to build gradle if you are going to run the project. So disabling the gradle sync to gradle project is senseless.

Comment: "And anyway you have to build gradle if you are going to run the project." Yes, I know that. But but I can do it manually if I need to, just like before. But my problem is not that: I start Android Studio and then Android Studio start Gradle Sync (every time happens this since the Andriod Studio 2.2 update for me, also if I don't change any code, just open and close the IDE, so it's senseless).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is what you want.

`gradle --stop`

Comment: it stops current gradle instance. but, studio starts another gradle instance.