# Set the startup configuration of Gradle syncing

Tags: android-studio

I started using Android Studio just yesterday, when I created my first project it started to do the Gradle building.

I thought it was going to be only an one time process for each project.

But that's really annoying, it always do "Gradle Refreshing" and "Gradle Syncing" on each task I do.

- When I save the project, it do Gradle Syncing.
- When I add an activity, it do Gradle Syncing.
- When I edit application package information, it do Gradle Syncing.
- etc.

I only agree that it should do Gradle Building once I try to build my application, but not all the time.

The causes which take place once Gradle Syncing is running:

- I can't do anything in the designer, nor the .java activities.
- All the buttons and features of Android Studio are locked.

and I have to wait until it finish (which usually take up to 1 minute), so I can do anything to my project.

Based on an answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35878520/6486232 - I followed what the user said, but my project is destroyed now (I think it was doing something important and I forced it..)

So I hope there's any configuration to do to not even start the Gradle Syncing task until I build the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might have noticed thats the gradle process is taking more time when you are connected to the internet

have you tried downloading the full gradle package   ? https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

it might be missing and thats why its taking time on trying to get it

1- open up the 'Terminal' tab of your Android Studio

2- type

```
gradlew
```

it should start the 63mb file download now ! keep the terminal box up and don't close it

edit- after that type `gradlew --stop` in the terminal

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I think Gradle is already pre-installed with Android Studio. and the problem is 'syncing Gradle' and not 'downloading Gradle'.

Comment: glad i helped at last. i require 50 reputation to comment on the answer u posted :)
however,keeping the gradle settings is always the best solution  - and if u tried to force stop it or something like that, u will end up with a very cheap android project.
i dont see its necessary to stop it,as its very important for the new changes to take action in the gradle init scripts

Answer (score 2):

The answer is here.

Thanks to @usamember - I understood him wrongly.

**BIG EDIT: To stop the Gradle sync on Android Studio startup ->** https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400099/6486232
*But to stop it while using Android Studio, complete reading this answer.*

@usamember meant to download the Gradle Terminal files first, and that can be done by typing the command which he provided, `gradlew`

It took 15 minutes for me to finish, (it depends on your internet connection).

Now you can easily type `gradlew --stop`

The result was:

```
F:\AndroidStudioProjects\RodentsMobile\RodentsMobile>gradlew --stop
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
.....................................................................................................................................
..............................................................................................................................
Unzipping C:\Users\HP\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to C:\Users\HP\.gradle\
wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv
Stopping daemon(s).
Gradle daemon stopped.
F:\AndroidStudioProjects\RodentsMobile\RodentsMobile>M`O^\MaO^ZMaO^\MaO^^MaO MaO"MaO%MaO&MaO'MaO'MaO'M`f^YM`f
'M`OMaO' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here is the success info:

```
Stopping daemon(s).
Gradle daemon stopped.
```

---

Starting Gradle daemon back is more simple.

- Type `gradlew` or `gradlew --daemon` in the Terminal

**EDIT:** Another way of starting Gradle back without errors, is trying to build your Android application.

- If you got an error like that:

> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
>  What went wrong:
> Unable to start the daemon process.
> This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
> For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
> Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
> Please read the following process output to find out more:
> -----------------------
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
>
>
>  Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> ```

Then start Android Studio as Administrator and type `gradlew` or `gradlew --daemon` again.

**EDIT:** Another way of starting Gradle back without errors, is trying to build your Android application.

Comment: Android Studio is very fast when I stopped the annoying 'Gradle syncing' process which was using a lot of my PC's CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check is there checked option (**Sync project with gradle before building, if needed**) in your settings, and if it is, uncheck it. **Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Sync project with gradle before building, if needed**. I hope it will help you.

Comment: That's not checked. Also it's not syncing only on Building the application :/

Comment: Hmmm, Maybe you have **+** sign at the end of some library you've included in your project. For example `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'`. If that is the case, change to specific version like: `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'`

Comment: Still the same problem. it's syncing Gradle.