# How to disable auto sync build.gradle.kts script in Android Studio(Artic Fox recent version)

Tags: android-studio, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I migrated groovy to kotlin dsl.

After changed to kotlin dsl (`build.gradle.kts`). Android-Studio do auto sync after any changes in `build.gradle.kts`. Before in `groovy` not auto synced. I always used 'sync now'(alt + enter)

solutions in stackOverFlow are not fit in Artic-Fox I think. and I could'n find any setting options.

from answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400099/13050313
no options that answered.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the way.

#### quick setting

1. double tap shift (shift + shift) for searching
2. write `reload`
3. click `Reload project after changes in the build scripts`

[image]

#### step by step

1. go `Settings`
2. go `Languages & Frameworks` > `Kotlin` > `Kotlin Scripting`
3. uncheck or check `Auto Reload` what you want

   - my case : unChecked `KotlinBuildScript` like below image

[image]